# Create DB trigger to crud operation for audit

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to create DB trigger to azure db that when user click change something in the table a trigger will write this event to a table,write what was changed ,timestemp etc.

Currently I have two basic questions.

1.This is my model

```
public class UserRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Boolean Address { get; set; }
    public Boolean Email { get; set; }
    public Boolean Work { get; set; }
    public Boolean Home { get; set; }
}

public class UserRolesDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UserRolesDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
       this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = My.GetDBConnectionString();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            this.Database.SqlQuery("here put the SQL")
        }

    }

        public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRolesCollection { get; set; }
    }
```

Should I put the trigger like this (in sqlQuery) if I want it to be created when I deploy my cloud service ?Currenlty the DB created in azure when Im doing deployment...

2.Assume that I want to copy all the fields with the DB triger from UserRoles table to UserRolesCopy and when they changed like **audit**, how should I write the SQL code?

```
my schema name is :UserDB
MyOrginal table is:UserRoles
I want it to copy to UserRoleCopy
```

I new to this topic and I've read the following page In MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

-- Windows Azure SQL Database Syntax
Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a table or view (DML Trigger)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name 
ON { table | view } 
 [ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ] 
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } 
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] } 
  AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] [ ; ] > }

<dml_trigger_option> ::= 
        [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
```

Comment: There are also *examples* given on that `CREATE TRIGGER` page - did you try adapting any of them and make an actual attempt to do this work yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following method to audit your table change :

1. Use Database Audit Specifications

   [Create a Server Audit and Database Audit Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280424.aspx)
2. CDC (Change Data Capture)

   [About Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx)
3. DML Trigger

>

```
Create Trigger yourSchema.TriggerName ON YourTable
AFTER INSERT, Update, Delete
AS Begin
  -- Log Deleted Rows and Old Value in Updated Rows
  Insert Into LogTable(UserName, Columns)
  Select CURRENT_USER, Columns
  From Deleted

  -- Log Inserted Row and New Value in Updated Rows
  Insert Into LogTable(UserName, Columns)
  Select CURRENT_USER, Columns
  From Inserted
End
```

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up,since I new to this topic ,where should I put the orginal table name (UserRoles )and the copied table (UserRolesCopy),and where should I put the table properties or key if its needed? ...2.what is the trigger name , log table,columans ?should I use it as-is hard coded? sorry for the basic question I really new to this topic...

Comment: Please see my edit. I suggest You to use method 1 for audit change of your data. If you can use method 1, tell me for more information.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot do it manually I need it to be deplyed when I deploy my azure cloud service(like it create the tables )is it possible?

Comment: I don't work with azure cloud service. and I don't know.